# How can I hold Popover box until my mouse moves away from it in Full calendar?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar in my angular project to display events . I am using popover to display activity and fire a new click event on a button in that popover. But my main issue is that this popover gets hidden when i try to drag mouse on that pop over. I want this popover to get displayed untill i move my mouse away from it.

```
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            var chk = $(event.target).css('display', 'block');
            element.popover({
                animation: false,
                delay: 300,
                html:true,
                content: '<div ng-show="checked"><button>abc</button><b>Item</b>:' + event.start + "<b>Fin</b>:" + event.end + "</div>",
                //offset: 10,
                //container: '#calendar',
                trigger: 'hover'
            });
```

Comment: What kind of popover did you use? Which library? You should tag your question with that because the issue seems to be related to the popover, rather than fullCalendar or angular

Comment: You can maybe use a setTimeout to the popover.close function(), to let the time the user click on the button. As @ADyson says, it's more come from your popover setting than fullcalendar

Comment: Thanx for the respnse  but i fixed the issue.

Comment: In that case please either post your solution below in the Answers section (it is totally legitimate to answer your own question), or, if the issue was some trivial thing like a typo which will not be of interest to anyone else, then you could just delete the question. Don't just leave your post hanging here uselessly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I fixed this by applying mouseenter and mouseleave events

```
            element.popover({
            animation: false,
            delay: 300,
            html:true,
            content: '<div ng-show="checked"><button>abc</button><b>Item</b>:' + event.start + "<b>Fin</b>:" + event.end + "</div>",
            //offset: 10,
            //container: '#calendar',
            trigger: 'hover'
            })
                .on("mouseenter", function () {
                    var _this = this;
                    $(this).popover("show");
                    $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
                        $(_this).popover('hide');
                    });
                }).on("mouseleave", function () {
                    var _this = this;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                            $(_this).popover("hide");
                        }
                    }, 300);
                });
```